# Is a good idea do processing of a large amount of data directly on database?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a database with a lot of web pages stored.

I will need to process all the data I have so I have two options: recover the data to the program or process directly in database with some functions I will create.

What I want to know is:

- do some processing in the database, and not in the application is a good
  idea?
- when this is  recommended and when not?
- are there pros and cons?
- is possible to extend the language to new features (external APIs/libraries)?

I tried retrieving the content to application (worked), but was to slow and dirty. My 
preoccupation was that can't do in the database what can I do in Java, but I don't know if this is true.

**ONLY a example:** I have a table called `Token`. At the moment, it has 180,000 rows, but this will increase to over 10 million rows. I need to do some processing to know if a word between two token classified as `Proper Name´ is part of name or not.

I will need to process all the data. In this case, doing directly on database is better than retrieving to application?

Comment: What kind of database are you dealing with?  I think the answer will depend on that.

Comment: @c0de: check the question tags.

Comment: I believe c0deNinja is talking about the *purpose* of the database.

Comment: The purpose of database is store all the info I have. The final purpose of my application is a database with some extracted data, and not the usage in a program. For this, I need to perform some text and statistical manipulation. The basic idea is all tables will have a lot of data and all the data must pass to various processing.

Comment: You could use a dedicated text search engine such as [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com) for your Token query: I use it with a 2+ million documents index and even advanced queries with wildcards (for partial matches) and ranking execute in a fraction of a second. You could even have a dedicated/hosted separatedly server  to balance the load in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My preoccupation was that can't do in the database what can I do in
>   Java, but I don't know if this is true.

No, that is not a correct assumption. There are valid circumstances for using database to process data. For example, if it involves calling a lot of disparate SQLs that can be combined in a store procedure then you should do the processing the in the stored procedure and call the stored proc from your java application. This way you avoid making several network trips to get to the database server.

I do not know what are you processing though. Are you parsing XML data stored in your database? Then perhaps you should use XQuery and a lot of the modern databases support it.

> ONLY an example: I have a table called Token. At the moment, it has
>   180,000 rows, but this will increase to over 10 million rows. I need
>   to do some processing to know if a word between two token classified
>   as `Proper Name´ is part of name or not.

Is there some indicator in the data that tells it's a proper name? Fetching 10 million rows (highly susceptible to OutOfMemoryException) and then going through them is not a good idea. If there are certain parameters about the data that can be put in a where clause in a SQL to limit the number of data being fetched is the way to go in my opinion. Surely you will need to do explains on your SQL, check the correct indices are in place, check index cluster ratio, type of index, all that will make a difference. Now if you can't fully eliminate all "improper names" then you should try to get rid of as many as you can with SQL and then process the rest in your application. I am assuming this is a batch application, right? If it is a web application then you definitely want to create a batch application to do the staging of the data for you before web applications query it.

I hope my explanation makes sense. Please let me know if you have questions.

Comment: No, is not XML. It's text, categorized words. What I want to do fits on Natural Language Processing. I edited my question and wrote one example of a thing I want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Directly interacting with the DB for every single thing is a tedious job and affects the performance...there are several ways to get around this...you can use indexing, caching or tools such as Hibernate which keeps all the data in the memory so that you don't need to query the DB for every operation...there are tools such as luceneIndexer which are very popular and could solve your problem of hitting the DB everytime...